# How can I push a custom variable to Google Analytics through Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am migrating an existing Google Analytics implementation to Google Tag manager. There are some custom variables used in the Analytics implementation.

Now I want to configure that custom variable in the Tag manager. I have searched this topic on the web and most of the resources pointing me to *‘More Settings’ -> ‘Custom Variables’* in the Tag configuration. But I don't see such option in the current Tag manager.

Has this feature being deprecated or is there any workaround to do this?

Note: Currently, in our GA dashboard custom variables are displayed under *'Audience' -> 'Custom' - 'Custom Variables'*. Users don't want any change to the current data representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way the Universal Analytics migration is going (currently in Phase 3 of 4), you should think about switching to that, where you can use up to 20 Custom Dimensions (very similar to custom variables). Older features implemented using classic GA will be deprecated, including Custom Variables (source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/?hl=en_US). Back to your question though: when you create a new tag, select "Classic Google Analytics" as the tag type, like so, and then under More Settings > Custom Variables, select "New Custom Variable".

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had created a Universal Analytics tag and therefore as you mentioned Custom variables will not be available.